# Decrypting cipher-block-chain XOR "encryption"

Tags: python, function, reverse

I got a challenge from my friend.
He said that I need to reverse the function, and I need to find inputs.
But, I am stuck for hours thinking the logic and how to write what I think in a code.

He gave me this algorithm:

```
def hash_cbc(input):
    initial = 'a'
    key = 'netsos'

    output = [ord(initial)]

    def enc(c, key, i):
        z = key[i % len(key)]
        return (c + ord(z)) ^ ord(z)

    for i in range(len(input)):
        prev_char = output[i]
        next_char = enc(prev_char, key, i) ^ ord(input[i])
        output.append(next_char)

    return output
```

the output of this algorithm must be:

```
97, 194, 299, 411, 533, 654, 768, 873, 965, 1066, 1164, 1272, 1399, 1512, 1603, 1706, 1792, 1895, 1994, 2110, 2215, 2310, 2404, 2517, 2645, 2762
```

I need to reverse the function so I can get inputs. Inputs must be a string.

Please help me, I have been stuck for hours and with no results.
I was thinking to reverse the XOR function, but really confused how to write it.

---

I was thinking these algorithm doing this

```
enc(prev_char, key, i) ^ 1st ordinal input = 1st output
enc(prev_char, key, i) ^ 2nd ordinal input = 2nd output
enc(prev_char, key, i) ^ 3rd ordinal input = 3rd output
```

etc doing that in a loop

but I am not sure how to reverse because there is 
"enc(prev_char, key, i)" part that makes me confusing

I also tried to make my own reverse code

```
def enc(c, key, i):
Awalan = input("Insert numbers: ")
Awalan_split = Awalan.split (', ')
Awalan_len = len(Awalan_split)

initial = 'a'
key = 'netsos'
output = [ord(initial)]
z = key[i % len(key)]
return (c + ord(z)) ^ ord(z)

for i in range(Awalan_len):
    prev_char = output[i]
    next_char = int(Awalan_split[i]) ^ enc(prev_char, key, i)
    char_convert = chr(next_char)
    return(char_convert)

print(char_convert)
```

but no luck, it just give me empty output.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: And where in your attempts to solve this do you need help exactly?

Comment: i was trying to reverse XOR (^) function, but no luck... maybe you can give me algorithm suggestion

Comment: Writing a program that does a given thing for you is not what we do here. StackOverflow exists to be a Q&A knowledgebase -- a collection of canonical questions (that someone other than you might face) and answers to them. If you can find a question in where you're stuck that has potential to be more widely applicable, removing the elements that are peripheral to that question to make that applicability more clear (and focusing the title on *that question*, vs what you're trying to do) would be helpful.

Comment: Ah thanks before.... so I need to be more "general" in this forum?

Comment: Trying to reverse XOR is a reasonable thing to ask about. Can you find the smallest possible example that illustrates your problem? For instance, can take out the code that operates on strings, and just focus on the first character, or even the first number (factoring out the ordinal conversion, *unless* you've established that the ordinal conversion is part of what doesn't work correctly?) Or is it only in the string code, and not the general XOR code, where things break down?

Comment: General in a sense, specific in a sense. General in that we want questions to be as reusable by others as possible (the ideal is we get as close as we can to a state where there's no more need to post more questions because they've all been asked and answered and can be searched). Specific in that we want each question posted to focus on exactly one well-specified question, providing the simplest possible code/inputs/&c. that can illustrate it.

Comment: First step, can you explain (to yourself) what this code does, every step of the way? What is its purpose, how does it work, what's the end result? Next step, pick a very simple example (e.g. one character) and on paper perform both the forward and reverse calculations. Performing the operations by hand will help you understand how to code it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XOR reverses itself.  A^B=C, C^B=A. Example:

```
>>> 123 ^ 456
435
>>> 435 ^ 456
123
```

The 2nd value of the result, 194, was computed by XORing the unknown original character with the result of the `enc()` function, so XORing 194 again with the `enc()` function should produce the original value.  Remember that `initial` is `'a'` and the last parameter of `enc` is the current index into the original string, so `0`:

```
>>> 194 ^ enc(ord('a'),'netsos',0)
99
>>> chr(99)
'c'
```

The 3rd value of the result, 299, was XORed with the encryption function using the previous value and the next character of the sequence, so XORing with the encryption function again should produce it:

```
>>> 299 ^ enc(194,key,1) # index (last parm) incremented
105
>>> chr(105)
'i'
```

Following this pattern, then unencrypt function should be:

```
output = []
for i in range(len(inp) - 1): # original will be one shorter.
    prev_char = inp[i]
    next_char = enc(prev_char, key, i) ^ inp[i+1]
    output.append(next_char)
```

Then just convert the ordinals generated back to characters:

```
return ''.join(chr(n) for n in output)
```

Here's everything tied together:

```
# factor out common stuff
initial = 'a'
key = 'netsos'
def enc(c, key, i):
    z = key[i % len(key)]
    return (c + ord(z)) ^ ord(z)

def hash_cbc(inp):
    output = [ord(initial)]

    for i in range(len(inp)):
        prev_char = output[i]
        next_char = enc(prev_char, key, i) ^ ord(inp[i])
        output.append(next_char)

    return output

def unhash_cbc(inp):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(inp) - 1):
        prev_char = inp[i]
        next_char = enc(prev_char, key, i) ^ inp[i+1]
        output.append(next_char)

    return ''.join(chr(n) for n in output)

expected_result = [97, 194, 299, 411, 533, 654, 768, 873, 965, 1066, 1164, 1272, 1399, 1512, 1603, 1706, 1792, 1895, 1994, 2110, 2215, 2310, 2404, 2517, 2645, 2762]

u = unhash_cbc(expected_result)
h = hash_cbc(u)
print(h == expected_result)
print(u)
```

Output:

```
True
cipheringblockingchaining
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! Very helpful & detailed explanation :D